# How to check if all strings in array are the same length c#

Tags: c#, arrays, char, string-length

for instance,

```
string[] text=new string[] {"string1", "string2", "string3"};
```

how do i know if all string's length in this array are equal?

Comment: `text.Select(x => x.Length).Distinct().Count() == 1`

Comment: `bool sameLength = text.All(item => item.Length == text[0].Length);`

Comment: @ 
Rand Random thx

Comment: _"without using 'for' or 'foreach'"_ - what's your actual problem?

Comment: @SᴇM - not cool enough

Comment: @ Rand Random yep

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You mean `== text[0].Length`, right?

Comment: @RandRandom ah, I see.

Comment: Like the first comment, except using a later version of Linq that has `DistinctBy()` to shorten it marginally: `bool allSameLength = text.DistinctBy(str => str.Length).Count() == 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
bool allSameLength = !text.Any(t => t.Length != text[0].Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using `for(each)` as requested:

```
string[] text = new string[] {"dsasaffasfasfafsa", "siuuuuu", "ewqewqeqeqewqeq"};
int index = 0, firstLength = -1;
bool allSameLength = true;
while(index < text.Length)
{
    int length = (text[index] + '\0').IndexOf('\0');
    firstLength = (index == 0) ? length : firstLength;
    allSameLength &= (length != firstLength) ;
    index += 1;
}

return allSameLength;
```

Comment: Kudos! I spot a consultant here: It's exactly what the user asked for, but probably not what he needed.

Comment: @PalleDue Thanks! I refuse to provide off-the-shelf solutions to homework on this site but we can still have a little fun, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that does not use `for(each)` and does not try to cheat by using a different type of loop (like `while`):

```
    string[] text = new string[] {"dsasaffasfasfafsa", "siuuuuu", "ewqewqeqeqewqeq"};

    List<string> texts = new List<string>();
    texts.Add(null);
    texts.AddRange(text);
    texts.Add(null);
    
    bool CheckSameLength(int index)
      => (texts[index + 1] == null) ? true
       : texts[index] == null ? CheckSameLength(1)
       : texts[index].Length == texts[index + 1].Length ? CheckSameLength(index + 1)              
       : false;
      
    return CheckSameLength(texts, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most ridiculous use of recursion?

```
public class Program {
  
  public static void Main() {
    string[] text = new string[] {"dsasaffasfasfafsa", "siuuuuu", "ewqewqeqeqewqeq"};
    Console.WriteLine(AllLengthsEqual(text));
  }

  public static bool AllLengthsEqual(string[] strArr) {
    return strArr == null ? true : (strArr.Length < 2 ? true : AllLengthsEqual(strArr, 0));
  }

  private static bool AllLengthsEqual(string[] strArr, int index) {
    return AllLengthsEqual(strArr, index + 1, strArr[index] != null ? strArr[index].Length : -1);
  }

  private static bool AllLengthsEqual(string[] strArr, int index, int prevLength) {    
    if (index < strArr.Length) {
      int thisLength = strArr[index] != null ? strArr[index].Length : -1;
      return (thisLength == prevLength) && AllLengthsEqual(strArr, index + 1, thisLength);
    }
    else 
      return true;    
  }
  
}
```